# What is the class equivalent to SharedPreferences in Ionic 2?

Tags: android, cordova, angular, ionic2

On Android you can use a [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) class to store small quantity of data. Example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

What is the class equivalent to SharedPreferences in Ionic 2? How can it be used?

Comment: @HassanShahzad I do not remember very well. But try this https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences

Comment: @HassanShahzad The answer Matt worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ionic 2 has a storage module. The docs are [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/). It doesn't use SharedPreferences under the hood, but will:

> "attempt to use IndexedDB, WebSQL, and localstorage, in that order."

Here is an example from the site I linked:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(storage: Storage) {

 // set a key/value
 storage.set('name', 'Max');

    // Or to get a key/value pair
    storage.get('name').then((val) => {
      console.log('Your name is', val);
    })
   }
}
```